# Where is DirectXMath supported?

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I am trying to work out where DirectXMath is supported. I know it is intended as the new thing going forwards from Windows 8, but there are no macro checks (e.g. against _WIN32_WINNT), and in my testing seems to work fine at least with Windows7 & VS2013. Unlike most MSDN docs, there doesn't seem to be a "platform requirements" section on its doc pages...

Is it just a question of the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DirectXMath primarily relies on the Visual Studio compiler intrinsics support. As a header in the Windows 8.x SDK, it officially only supports Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio 2013, and Windows Vista or later. It only has a single Win32 API dependency (`IsProcessorFeaturePresent`), even that is optional.

It is technically possible to use it for Windows XP, but there's no official SDK configuration that would provide it in the headers that are supported on Windows XP.

There's no official support for non-MSVC compilers, and I've heard there are a few minor issues with the headers trying to use the Intel compiler.

See [Introducing DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/).

*Note:* A few of the intrinsics I use in [DirectXMath extensions](https://walbourn.github.io/directxmath-sse-sse2-and-arm-neon/) blog series make use of VS 2012 only or VS 2013 only intrinsics, but the base library is compatible with VS 2010 SP1 or later.

> **UPDATE:** The DirectXMath library is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) under the MIT license, although I no longer support VS 2010. You can use the NuGet package to use it with Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

> The DirectXMath library is designed for C++ developers working on
>   games and DirectX graphics in Windows Store apps and traditional
>   desktop apps for Windows 8 and later.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
So, since Win8 (which doesn´t mean parts of it can´t run below too)
And, as an example, XMMatrixAffineTransformation:

> Platform Requirements
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 or Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2012 with the Windows SDK for Windows 8. Supported for Win32
>   desktop apps, Windows Store apps, and Windows Phone 8 apps.

Comment: The thing is the SDK's have often historically supported older versions (otherwise surely windows.h etc. would always error out if given an old _WIN32_WINNT value or similar), and it just says "Win32 desktop apps", which applies to the older Window's versions as well. Other API's are more specific, e.g. "Minimum supported client  Windows Vista [desktop apps only]". And MS has officially supported some new DirectX things on old platforms (e.g. didn't XAUdio2 get an implementation via DirectSound on XP rather than the shiny WSAPI elsewhere?)

Comment: Well, I understand *Windows 8 [and on Win8 available for] desktop apps, store apps...*. And this has nothing to do with other APIs